# Form::open() is generating an https URL instead of http. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel's `Form::open()` is generating an HTTPS URL for the POST location instead of HTTP.  How can I force this to work?

Here is the `Form::open()` code:

```
{{ Form::open(URL::to('someurl/somedest', 'POST', array('class' => 'form-horizontal'))); }}
```

Comment: Made the question make more sense for what was actually going on - hopefully this will show up in a search for someone doing the same bad things as me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form::open()` should only generate an `http` url, `Form::open_secure()` is for `https` forms.    Also, you don't need the `URL::to()` in there. Try this:

```
{{ Form::open('someurl/somedest', 'POST', array('class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
```

Here's the [documentation page](http://laravel.com/docs/views/forms#opening-a-form), for reference.

Comment: That's the problem, though - I'm not using open_secure(), and it's still generating the https link.  Will the Form::open translate it to the correct route?  Sorry, I'm coming from a Rails / Django background and some of this routing black magic is a little too dark for me. :S

Comment: I removed the URL::to - and that's definitely the issue. Thanks!